# How to convert dates between json-net (C# client) and Spring (java server)

Tags: java, c#, json, spring, json.net

I have a server (Spring Boot) and a client (written in C# and using json-net library for conversion). I need to be able to pass around a timestamp between the client and the server. But I cannot figure how to make them compatible (without manually generating the formats). Here is what I ended up with (the issue is later):

**Client (C#)**

```
public async Task<TestResponse> TestTimeAsync(DateTime timestamp)
    {
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = BaseUri;

        string dateStr = timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

        var query = string.Format("test?timestamp={0}", dateStr);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(query);

        var responseJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestResponse>(responseJson);

        return resp;
    }

public class TestResponse
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And in order for dates to be correctly formatted inside objects passed to the server via JSON I did this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}


public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public static string DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff";
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = DATE_FORMAT;
    }
}
```

**Server (Spring)**
TestConroller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public TestDate testDate(
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1970-01-01T01:00:00.000") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") Date timestamp) {
    TestDate ret = new TestDate();
    ret.date = timestamp;
    return ret;
}
```

TestDate.java (response model)

```
public class TestDate{
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    Date date;
}
```

This sorta works - I got the conversion working. However, here are the issues:

a) I had to do a custom converter on the client side, because none of the standard ones seem to be matching between Spring and C#. For some reason even ISO8601 gave different outputs on both sides.

b) This doesn't include the timezone and this causes data corruption. I.e. I pass 2017-03-03T**10**:00:00.000 to the server, test code returns the same value, but it now reads as 2017-03-03T**12**:00:00.000.

c) I can't find a standard formatting pattern to add the timezone and have it compatible between platforms. e.g. C# 'zzz' generates "+05:00" while Spring's 'Z' expects "+0500". I could manually generate this string, but there should be standard way, right?

d) I thought about just passing around a long containing milliseconds, but that would make the data model ugly (and not sure if would solve the issue tbh).

So what would be the right way to pass the timestamps between the client and the server? Maybe I'm doing something wrong or there is a completely alternative solution?